# Save as Option in IE for .step file is invalid

Tags: internet-explorer

`<a href="http://www.xx.com/abc.STEP"></a>`

abc.STEP is .step file, But when Save as Option in IE, it change .step to .html.

[image]

So How to solve?

Comment: I find an example website and I try to download the `.STEP` file in IE. I use "Save target as" and it can save the `.STEP` file correctly. You could check [the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDlPz.gif). You could check if the source of the link isn't a `.STEP` file or try to change the file extension name manually. If the issue still persists, you could provide [a minimal, reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can test it and see how to help.

Comment: @YuZhou This is demo link: https://rateltalk.com/2019/10/22/hello-world/; The second KF10 link Incorrect. You can try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the demo you provided and reproduced the issue. I think it's due to the different format of the `.STEP` file. I opened the files directly in IE and the formats are not the same: [first KF10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuKIT.png), [second KF10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oq9Vf.png).

When I use F12 dev tools to check the second file, it even [doesn't have a `<!DOCTYPE html>`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y84LE.png) so it's not a standard html page, this might also be the cause of the issue.

My suggestion is that you can change the file extension name manually when you download the file in IE 11. Because the issue only occurs in certain file and is largely caused by the file itself.